# Are turkish hazelnuts edible?

Tags: botany, food, toxicology, trees

The title of this question is Google suggestion verbatim, when I tried to write it. Yet, I found no answer specifically for Turkish hazelnuts.

[Turkish hazelnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corylus_colurna) is a tree and it's fruit looks different from normal hazelnuts growing on hazelnut shrubs.

One such tree is planted close to my house, so I was wondering if I could eat all the nuts on the ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off all let me say something about this tree.

---

Turkish hazelnut (*Corylus colurna*) is a slow growing pyramidal tree approximately around 25 m (82ft) tall, with a stout trunk up to 1.5 m (4 ft 11 in) in diameter. Leaves are deciduous, rounded, 6-15 cm long and 5-13 cm across, softly hairy on both surfaces. *Corylus colurna* is actually the largest species of hazel. The name Korylos (korys) comes from Greek and means helmet. The tree is dioecious.

---

Nuts are about 1-2 cm long, surrounded by a thick, softly spiny and bristly involucre (husk) 3cm diameter. The nuts are born in cluster of 3-8 together. The nuts mature in September and are edible, with a taste similar to common hazel (*Corylus avellana*). The nuts have a very hard shell, approximately 3 mm thick, which it makes them a little hard to open. Nut production is very irregular and occurs every two to three years.

---

Source

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corylus_colurna
http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=277856
https://www.chicagobotanic.org/plantinfo/tree_alternatives/turkish_hazelnut